# Copy Constructor not called by synthesized property setter in Objective C++ code

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

We all know how sparsely documented Objective-C++ is. I can't find anything on this, but I'm also finding it hard to find suitable unambiguous search terms.
So, Stackoverflow to the rescue (I hope)!

I have a C++ class that I have an instance of within an Objective-C(++) class (and I have the project setting enabled for constructors/ destructors to be called).

This all works fine until I try to expose the instance via a `@synthesize`d property. I make it an `assign` property (as Obj-C retain counting is not applicable). The property appears to work except when I set the instance I would expect the copy constructor to be involved.
What I actually see is that a temporary instance is created (the copy constructor on *that* is invoked) - which is all expected. But the copy constructor on the ivar instance is *not* called. The values are "magically" set. I'm presuming that the `@synthesize`d code is doing something like a `memcpy` as the final step. This is fine for C `struct`s, but not so helpful for C++ `class`es where the correctness of the code depends on the copy constructors and assignment operators being called appropriately.

Has anyone looked into this in any more depth, got it working, or confirmed that it is not possible to hold C++ objects as ivars in an Obj-C(++) class and have copy constructors called by `@synthesize`d property setters?

(I can post sample code for all this if necessary - but even the minimal version is a screenful or so).

Answer (score 5):

Uhm, if I'm not confused, it's perfectly reasonable that the copy constructor is not called. Do you expect that ivar to be magically destructed and copy-constructed? I guess that's against C++'s rules. If the synthesized setter is conceptually

```
-(void)setFoo:(Foo)foo_{
    foo=foo_;
}
```

then `operator=` should be called, rather than the copy constructor.

**That said**, the `operator=` is not called either, bummer (10.6.4, gcc 4.2.1.)! Here's the sample code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

class Foo{
    int a,b;
public:
    Foo():a(0),b(0){NSLog(@"default constructor for %p",this);}
    Foo(const Foo&foo):a(foo.a),b(foo.b){NSLog(@"copy constructor for %p",this);}
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& foo){
    NSLog(@"assignment operator for %p",this);
        a=foo.a;
        b=foo.b;
        return *this;
    }
};

@interface Bar:NSObject {
    Foo foo;
}
@property (assign) Foo foo;
@end

@implementation Bar
@synthesize foo;
@end

int main(){
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Bar* bar=[[Bar alloc] init];
    Foo foo;
    bar.foo=foo;
    [pool drain];
}
```

Save it into `boo.mm`,  I had:

```
$ g++ -fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors boo.mm -framework Foundation
$ ./a.out
2010-09-04 12:32:06.570 a.out[24352:903] default constructor for 0x10010cdc8
2010-09-04 12:32:06.572 a.out[24352:903] default constructor for 0x7fff5fbff7e0
2010-09-04 12:32:06.573 a.out[24352:903] copy constructor for 0x7fff5fbff7d0
$
```

Now, I had the explicit setter I wrote above instead of `@synthesize Foo`, I correctly had

```
$ ./a.out
2010-09-04 12:42:22.206 a.out[24417:903] default constructor for 0x10010cdc8
2010-09-04 12:42:22.209 a.out[24417:903] default constructor for 0x7fff5fbff7e0
2010-09-04 12:42:22.210 a.out[24417:903] copy constructor for 0x7fff5fbff7d0
2010-09-04 12:42:22.210 a.out[24417:903] assignment operator for 0x10010cdc8
```

The clang source code for the generation of the synthesized setter is [this](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/CodeGen/CGObjC.cpp?revision=112047&view=markup), see `GenerateObjCSetter`. There, it eventually tests whether C++ assignment operator is needed. I would say it's a gray area, not well-documented but currently being implemented...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have said copy constructor *or* assignment operator. I was watching both just in case :-) The copy constructor was called when creating the temp.

Comment: So are you just confirming by experiment what I am seeing, or have you read somewhere that this is expected?

Comment: I just observed what you said. I don't find any explicit documentation.  You can check the source code of gcc or clang to see what they do.

Comment: Found the corresponding code in clang repository, apparently the latest clang does generate the assignment operator, see the edited response. Anyway I don't think it's wise to rely on a not-well-documented cutting-edge technology...

Comment: Thanks Yuji. Sounds like it's not safe to rely on this right now - which is a real shame for my library. The worst thing is I thought I had this working - but I had an error in my test that was hiding it. So I got quite far into my implementation before hitting this.

Comment: @Yuji you are correct. I tested which branch of the if clang follows, and it is the second one, which emits GetCopyStructFn (a memcpy as Phil mentioned. (I submitted a bug to the llvm project (at http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8653), and they will fix it soon.) I image g++ does the same. -- The good news is there is a work-around! Just set the property to be nonatomic, and clang (and g++) will Emit correct assignment code! (third if branch)

Comment: @jbenet: thanks for reporting this to llvm. I was too lazy; thanks to you many will be saved!

Comment: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8653 shows that it has been fixed recently. It will probably take some time to be shipped with any release. Cheers!

Comment: For any stumbling on this question, I've just tested Yuji's code on Xcode 7.1.1 (clang-700.1.76), and it works fine (the assignment operator is indeed called, -fobjc-call-cxx-cdtor is not needed).

Answer (score 0):

The general rule with properties is, if you need specific behaviour that the default boilerplate that gets generated cannot provide you, write your own `-setFoo:` method for your `foo` property which does what you need it to. Automatic synthesis of properties are meant for the common case, they are not going to be applicable everywhere. In those cases, provide your own setter or getter for the property.

Comment: What I'm really after is confirmation that this is how the generated property code actually works. It's not much of a stretch to expect it to behave that way. If it doesn't it's quite a problem for what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Phil Nash: why is it a problem?  You just need to write your own setter.

Comment: Because my C++ class is "library" code that should be used all over the place. If synthesized properties don't work correctly wrt assignment then it's game over for my library.