# (iphone) is it ok to define @property for a c++ class/struct?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

I am mixing c++ and objectc.
In particular, I'm adding a c++ class/struct variable to object-c header, and if this is legit?

For example,

```
@interface MyView : UIView
{
   MyCppClass  cppVariable;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) MyCppClass cppVariable;
@end
```

and at implementation file, @synthesize cppVariable; as well.

Comment: Don't know whether it's legit, but you cannot store a C++ class directly, only pointers to it. It's a limitation of Objective-C++. So instead of `MyCppClass cppVariable;` you need to have `MyCppClass *cppVariable;`.

Comment: AFAIK, everything of a user-defined type should be a pointer. That is the reason you can't have a `NSString` but only `NSString*` etc.,

Comment: @DarkDust @Mahesh That rule doesn’t apply to C++ objects. Non-pointer C++ objects can be used as local or instance variables in Objective-C++.

Comment: @DarkDust you can certainly store c++ types/values in objc instances when compiling objc++. make sure you implement default constructors, and enable the compiler flag which calls the c++ objects' constructors/destructors. it works great. the rationale for many people to avoid c++ ivars by value in objc is that they want to allow (strict) objc programs to use the objc class in question, without forcing clients to compile everything as objc++. similarly, you can pass c++ types by value or reference 'through' objc selectors.

Comment: @Justin been a long time, but got questions. compiler generated default constructors wouldn't suffice? what's the compiler flag to call c++ objects' constructros/destructors

Comment: @Eugene if the compiler generated default ctor is suitable and can be created (e.g. all members also have suitable default ctors); yes you can use that and you won't need to write your own. that's often not the case for objects have been written to favor initialization. `-fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors` is the flag, and `GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS` is Xcode's alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is described in [this official document on Objective-C++](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1), you **can** have non-pointer C++ objects inside Objective-C classes. They are correctly constructed and destructed, if you use the option `-fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors` in GCC / clang.

The situation for `@sythesiz`ing non-pointer C++ `@property` is not as clear, because the documentation is lacking. The behavior sometimes depends on the compiler used, as was discussed e.g. in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642979/copy-constructor-not-called-by-synthesized-property-setter-in-objective-c-code). The Clang team is trying to implement the right thing, but I don't think it's available for now.

So, stick to using a pointer to C++ classes if you want to `@synthesize`. Otherwise, implement your own setter and getter.

Comment: Indeed. For what is worth, Apple’s Core Audio examples use non-pointer C++ objects as instance variables of Objective-C classes. As for declared properties, I agree with Yuji: there’s still some undefined behaviour, some of which varies amongst compiler versions. If the OP really needs declared properties, pointers to C++ objects are a more stable solution.

Comment: +1 *although* i disagree with one thing: you don't need 'to stick to using pointers' for this reason. you should not use raw pointers for all the reasons c++ devs avoid using them. you can pass by pointer if you like, you can use @property to declare a property, but you must provide your own implementation (read: @synthesize is not allowed for value c++ types). also, c++ with clang is not ready for production use so... if your c++ manage to compile now with clang, expect the possibility that it will not compile or may execute differently in the future due to changes in the compiler. (cont)

Comment: (cont) i'm not trying to bash clang, just reminding readers that it's still in active development, and should not be relied on for critical programs at this time. otherwise, it's proven to be a very promising project so far, and in other domains.

Comment: I agree with you heartily, @Justin. Editted my answer.

Comment: so with c++ pointer, @property/@synthesize (retain,assign) would work? I guess assign may not be a problem, but retain does work?

Comment: I don't think `retain` works. `retain` works by sending `retain` to the Objective-C object anyway.

Comment: First link is no longer valid, please fix