# How do objective-C properties function with C++ objects

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

So I am really curious as to how different kinds of properties work with C++ objects.

For example say I have a property which I declare like this:

```
@property (atomic,assign) myClass::sp_t propertyName;
```

How is this object treated when I call the setter method?  Is it simply assigned using operator=() thereby allowing the class to copy itself using it's operator=() method?

It seems like there might be some special handing of C++ object properties though, as I ran into a linker error while compiling a test program.

```
Symbol not found: _objc_copyCppObjectAtomic
```

This was with an assign property, so what is really going on here?

What do the generated getters and setters look like for C++ objects?

Comment: i don't know that you can use `atomic` with non-POD, and non cocoa object. but good enough question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Constructor not called by synthesized property setter in Objective C++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642979/copy-constructor-not-called-by-synthesized-property-setter-in-objective-c-code).  That should answer everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assign` qualifier just tells the compiler to generate an assignment statement without any forays into the memory-management aspect of Objective-C, so `operator=()` doesn't get called.  If you need it to be called, override the setter and do so yourself.  As for the `atomic` qualifier, the compiler should generate a special inline function with the signature

```
void objc_copyCppObjectAtomic(void *dest, const void *src, void (*copyHelper) (void *dest, const void *source));
```

It's just an atomic setter that does a safe pointer assignment for the object by default, but it can be [given a new handler](https://github.com/j4n0/objc4-532/blob/master/test/atomicProperty.mm) to support custom assignment very easily.

That linker error is a bug in older versions of clang that prevented that special setter function from being found and inlined by the compiler.

Comment: "The assign qualifier just tells the compiler to generate an assignment statement without any forays into the memory-management aspect of Objective-C, so operator=() doesn't get called." This is contradictory. An assignment statement with a C++ type *will* call the `operator=()` if there is one.

Comment: @newacct You're assuming that assignment is even used at all in the generated copy helper.

Comment: well, you said "The assign qualifier just tells the compiler to generate an assignment statement without any forays into the memory-management aspect of Objective-C"

Comment: @newacct If you have a way that you feel would make that sentence less ambiguous to you, be my guest and edit it in.  I feel that the purpose of the sentence was to show that `assign` allows the compiler to generate a simple assignment, rather than calls to `-retain` or `-copy`